# showing random emojis inside cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how do I show random emojis inside cells of a tableview? I guess I need something like a active dictionary of all the emojis I want to use and then I need to call them in every cell, right or wrong? Sorry, but I'm a beginner at programming in general, hope you can help me

Comment: As you haven't supplied what code you have tried; I can only comment not correct or supply an answer, but you will certainly already have an array set up from which your tableview is populated. Then at the same time, you can populate additionally from a separate array that has had the emoji ( or character code ) randomly chosen from the whatever UTF table you wish to use ). welcome to coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep your emojis in a separate text file like so

emojis.txt

And here's the code for your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let emojis: [String] = {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "emojis", withExtension: "txt")!
        let list = try! String(contentsOf: url).map { String($0) }
        return list.shuffled()
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "row \(indexPath.row) - \(emojis[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image: random emojis]

Comment: and by that I can create an outlet of the label from the Storyboard to display the emojis at the right place?

Comment: Where do you want to display the emojis? You possibly have to subclass the table view cell

Comment: over a button but inside my content view of the cell, if thats what you mean. Right now I got the same emoji as a Label over the button...

Comment: If you already have the cell configured and IBOutlet connected, it's a simple matter of placing the emoji into the right label.

Comment: but I want a random emoji in every cell so there won't be the same one over and over again - sadly your code is giving me this error "Value of type '[String]' has no member 'shuffled'"